# Submit DS record to parent zone in DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, dnssec

I have setup DNSSEC for my domain [shabdiznet.com](http://www.shabdiznet.com/) and checked it at http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/shabdiznet.com the only problem is

> No DS records found for shabdiznet.com in the com zone

as you may see . also i found same old question [Adding DS record to parent in DNS](https://serverfault.com/questions/180881/adding-ds-record-to-parent-in-dns) without answer to my question because i already finished the https://dlv.isc.org/ .

**How to Submit DS record to .com zone ? (with sample please)**

Comment: You should submit them to registrar for your domain. http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/resources/dnssec-registrars/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To submit your DS record to your parent zone (com), you will need to do it via your registrar (who then provisions it to the registry -- Verisign).

Your registrar appears to be Onlinenic. I'm not sure if they support DS record provisioning; you will have to contact them. If they don't, you would have to transfer your domain to a registrar that actually does. GoDdady does, but there are others but check with them before you make the jump. The other thing you could try is to convince Onlinenic to manually submit the DS record for you (even if they don't support it in their web interface.) If they agree to do it, that might be ok if you're not planning on rolling over your KSK for a long time and are reasonably confident that you can keep it safe.